# Geopandas sjoin seems to be returning union rather than intersection

Tags: geospatial, geopandas

**I'm trying to break up a large set of NREL wind data by assigning state, then working with each state individually.**

I have two sets of this NREL data--one that is simply a wind_class with no exclusions applied, and one where exclusions have been applied for urban areas, unsuitable land, wildlife preserves, etc. (Available here: https://www.nrel.gov/gis/data-wind.html, look for the two "United States Wind Power Class" datasets)

The two datasets do not have any common IDs that would allow me to easily identify the same 1/3-degree latitude x 1/3-degree longitude cell between the two (this is how they are allegedly arranged). Both datasets have variables labeled "gid" and "id", but these do not line up between datasets when I plot the same slices based on either ID.

**So, I want to use Geopandas' sjoin function to identify overlapping areas between the NREL datasets for each state, but here is my problem:**

I assigned state to rows of each NREL dataset by joining them to a dataset of US borders via sjoin. Its default behavior is supposed to be "intersects", which seems like it should only return NREL data that lies within the borders of a state. (US borders dataset available here: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2017-nation-u-s-current-state-and-equivalent-national)

After running this first sjoin, the state-by-state NREL datasets w/no exclusions mostly follow state lines--some cells that were assigned to a given state lie just outside of its borders, but that is fine.

Unfortunately, the state-by-state NREL datasets w/exclusions have large areas that do **not** obey state lines, but which Geopandas assigned to particular states anyway.

One particularly bad offender here is my Nebraska dataset, which seems to include most of the Midwest, despite most of this area being well outside of Nebraska's borders. The other Midwestern states are the same, which is killing me, because the Midwest generally appears to be a great place to site wind turbines, and I would really like to use this data.

- [Nebraska, with the misbehaving NREL dataset for NE w/exclusions plotted in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHRqU.png)

I tried rerunning this sjoin with all three of the available ops ("intersects", the default; "contains"; "within") but none of them are giving me what I expect, which would be only the part of the NREL dataset within Nebraska's borders.

What am I not understanding about how Geopandas' sjoin function, and how it works?

That was a long explanation, thanks for being patient and reading the whole thing. Here is some sample code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

us_state = 'NE'
filename = 'nrel_no_exclusions_{}.geojson'.format(us_state)

print("Reading NREL dataset w/exclusions for {} ".format(us_state),time.strftime('%X %x %Z'))
nrel_w_exclusions = gpd.read_file('{}/nrel_w_exclusions_by_state/nrel_w_exclusions_{}.geojson'.format(disk_dir,us_state),driver='GeoJSON')


within_pls = gpd.sjoin(nrel_w_exclusions,
                       lower48_borders.loc[lower48_borders['STUSPS'] == us_state,
                                           ['STUSPS','geometry']],
                       how='left',
                       op='within') # <--also tried "intersects" and "contains" here

fig = plt.figure()
ax = lower48_borders.loc[lower48_borders['STUSPS'] == us_state].plot(color='whitesmoke',edgecolor='black')
within_pls.plot(ax=ax,alpha=.3,color='green')
```

Comment: boil this down to a hand-coded, very simple geometry. A couple of overlapping square would work. Then do you get the expected result?

Comment: Thanks, that was a good suggestion. [Here's what I found](https://github.com/iamjeremybe/documents_to_share/blob/master/Playing%20with%20Geopandas%20sjoin.ipynb). In short--an sjoin seems to always return a full shape, intact, and not the intersection, or parts of a shape that contains or is within another shape. I confused op='intersects' with the behavior of the completely separate .intersection() method.

Comment: Now, the obvious followup--what can I do to get the result I actually wanted, which was the intersection of the two datasets? Will I need to apply .intersection() to each row of the NREL dataset, to get a set of cells that lie within each state's borders?

Comment: Can you rewrite this question to only include the small example in the notebook and also display the resulting geodataframe as text? i wonder if there's a column in there that classifies each geometry

Comment: ohh shoot. you don't want `sjoin`, you want overlay: http://geopandas.org/set_operations.html

Comment: OHHHH. I can't tell you how many times I skimmed that exact page without realizing what I was looking at. I need to test this out, but I'm sure that is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for being patient with a Geopandas newbie.

Answer (score 0):

.overlay() was the answer. Thanks, Paul H.

```
within_pls = gpd.overlay(nrel_w_exclusions,
                       lower48_borders.loc[lower48_borders['STUSPS'] == us_state,['geometry']],
                       how='intersection')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = lower48_borders.loc[lower48_borders['STUSPS'] == 'NE'].plot(color='whitesmoke',edgecolor='black')
within_pls.plot(ax=ax,alpha=.3,color='green')
```

[image]